# Increase image quality using Base64 string or other techniques

Tags: android, image, mongodb, bitmap, base64

I'm playing with image uploading on android and the first method I encountered to do so is using the Base64 codification, however I noticed that the image quality is drastically lowered.

Do you have any suggestion or know other ways to upload an image to a MongoDB keeping a good quality?

---

Code I'm actually using:

```
public static String toBase64(Bitmap image) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
    return Base64.encodeToString(stream.toByteArray(), Base64.NO_WRAP);
}

public static Bitmap fromBase64(String encodedImage) {
    byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(encodedImage, Base64.DEFAULT);
    return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);
}
```

And here's what I use to capture the image:

```
private void captureImage() {
    Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        Bitmap image = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        uploadImage(image);
    }
}
```

Comment: because you are compressing the image!

Comment: base64 encoding decoding does not change anything. So it is in the manupulation of your Bitmap. You are not showing where your Bitmap is coming from. If you want to upload files then do not use Bitmap and BitmapFactory.